# Powershell script does not run in infinite loop

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run this script in infinite loop:

```
$UNC = "\\pawelu\IELTS9"
$hostname = "pawelu"
$val = 1

start-transcript -path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\new.txt -append;

while($true) { 
Get-Date -format o;
start-sleep -s 3; write-host "UNC available... " -nonewline;
test-path $UNC;
$pingTest = test-connection -computername $hostname -count 1 -Quiet;  
write-host "ICMP is succesfull ... " $pingTest
write-host "Can write a file ... " -NoNewline
try {

$testPath = join-path $UNC ([IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())
new-item -path $testPath -ItemType file -ErrorAction Stop > $null


add-content $testPath SampleText
return $true

}catch
    {return $false
    }
    finally{

         remove-item $testPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
}
```

However it stops after running one time. If I remove Try,catch and finally block it keeps on going after I stop it manually and that is want I want. Thus, I think the flaw is somewhere there but cannot figure it out. How do I make it this script to keep on running?

Comment: Well, first get rid of the > $null and break in the catch section to have a look at the exception that could be thrown ($_.Exception). The "return $true" won't help either keeping your loop going. Return breaks out of your function and if you are not in a function out of your script.

Comment: You´re right. I have input all the code into the function and now it can run in infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I make it this script to keep on running?

Stop making the script `return`.

Simply remove the `return $true` statement from the `try` block.

If you want the loop to continue even when an error occurs, remove `return $false` from the `catch` block as well

Comment: Thanks, you were right about not using return. Still learning coding. To run it in infinite I followed @MartinMaat comment.